# Open ftp protocol in WinSCP from chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ftp, winscp, protocol-handler

On a day to day basis I need to access various FTP servers. I have a ftp:// protocol link for each of them in our webinterface. Everytime I click them, Chrome opens them in a new tab in its built-in "FTP client" instead of WinSCP (the FTP client I've set in windows as the default ftp:// protocol handler).

How can I make chrome opening the ftp:// protocol in my systems default application? Why is this working with nearly every protocol but ftp:// by default?

Comment: WinSCP can be registered to handle file transfer protocol URL addresses. See the winscp.net article [Protocol URL Addresses](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_url). I don't know how well this Windows feature is supported by Chrome.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, but thats what I've done already. But unfortunately Chrome ignores that and still opens FTP links in its own directory listing page.

Comment: I found out why, more info in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found that Chrome does not launch external programs for
custom URL handlers, only websites, for security reasons.

You need an extension for that, which communicates with the web-page
through Message Passing and using
[Native messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#native-messaging).

I have not been able to find such an extension for WinSCP,
but I did find a couple of extensions that may be able to launch
external programs with parameters:

- [External Application Button](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/external-application-butt/bifmfjgpgndemajpeeoiopbeilbaifdo/related?hl=en)
  This extension is used by Trello to create a button that launches
  their application, as described in the article
  [Ability to launch SalesMap from a chrome extension button](https://trello.com/c/zm7O17Df/111-ability-to-launch-salesmap-from-a-chrome-extension-button), but its version is only 0.2.8, meaning in alpha or beta
  testing.
- [Open in external app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-in-external-app/okdopehcdgnellkaldfnaemhbpciplem?hl=en)
  This is version 0.3, last updated on September 2016,
  so it does not look as if it is still in active development.

I have no idea how well do these extensions work, but I do not think
you are looking to write your own extension if they
do not work out.